# Three outstanding features you probably didn't know they exist

Tags: discussion, tagging, events, blog

did you know there are features on [Ethereum Stack Exchange](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/) which are currently barely utilized (or not at all)? I would like to take the time today to introduce you three features you probably like to use in 2017.

I will keep it short and informative as I know it's almost weekend and you are in hurry to switch from your office computer to your $HOME computer.

---

#### Project-specific tags

Questions on Ethereum Stack Exchange are organized in [tags](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/tags). You should utilize them to not only tag all your question with [go-ethereum](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/go-ethereum) but also with your custom project. Some popular examples: [truffle](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/truffle), [ethereum-studio](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ethereum-studio), and most recently [status-im](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-im).

The benefit is not only that you can organize your questions, but also to [subscribe to new questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254318/1260906) posted about your project: Hover over the tag and find the subscribe button. This includes email-notifications!

To create a tag, just start with a canonical question about "What is foo bar?" and tag it with [foo-bar](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foo-bar). **Make sure it's a high-quality post, and [on-topic for our site](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)**. Don't forget to subscribe. If you can not create tags yet, approach us to retag your question. And while you are asking about your own project already, you should also self-answer your question.

---

#### Events in the Ethereum community

There is a feature called *community events*. If you plan any Ethereum-related conference, meetup, or any other kind of get-together, just create a post on [meta](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/) promoting the event and tag it with [events](/questions/tagged/events). We will be able to link your post to a side-wide community event which will be promoted on the whole Ethereum subsite for 14 days prior the event start. Just like [EDCON did today](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/407/87).

---

#### Community-driven blog

Everyone knows [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). But did you know [BlogOverflow](https://blogoverflow.com/)? With joining the Stack Exchange network, we are able to host our own community blog about Ethereum, Solidity, Swarm, Whisper, and the Web 3.0 in general.

To get this bootstrapped, we need 3-5 interested (technical) writers who are willing to contribute once per month. Or 1 enthusiast who pledges to write an article once a week :-)

Sounds like a good idea? Please get in touch with me for details on how to proceed.

---

If you have any questions, please approach [me or any other member of the Stack Exchange moderator team](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators). The fastest way, is [posting on meta](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/), or for fast inquiries, leave a comment here.

Have a nice weekend,
5chdn